# org.json.JSONException: A JSONArray text must start with '[' at 1 [character 2 line 1]

Tags: java, json

I have exception when I want to read JSON array from local address php.
String in php looks like this:

```
[{"firstname":"ime1","lastname":"prezime1"},{"firstname":"ime2","lastname":"prezime2"},{"firstname":"ime3","lastname":"prezime3"}]
```

And my code for loading looks like this:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray("http://192.168.1.23/get_people.php");
```

Exceptoin is:

```
org.json.JSONException: A JSONArray text must start with '[' at 1 [character 2 line 1]
```

Comment: What is the output if you *actually* call http://192.168.1.23/get_people.php ?

Comment: Here it is in Chrome: http://prntscr.com/dyf4pt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an exception because your application *never* calls your service url http://192.168.1.23/get_people.php. So, when you use `new JSONArray("http://192.168.1.23/get_people.php")`, the application tries to create a JSONArray using the string "http://192.168.1.23/get_people.php", and not considering the return value of your ws.

There are many ways to consume a WS, you can look at [restTemplate](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/), [cxf](http://www.nibodha.com/blog/simple-rest-client-using-cxf-webclient-api/) or other library.

Comment: Thanks! I will go explore it, and try to fix problem